# Hover over an area a text should appear

Tags: python, data-visualization, geojson, folium

I am currently viewing the neighborhoods. However, when I hover the mouse over it, I want a text to be displayed with the neighborhood and the average price. I have pasted my code and my card what I made. Below you can see how I would like it.

How can I display a text when I hover over it?

```py
import folium
from folium.plugins import FastMarkerCluster
from branca.colormap import LinearColormap

map_ams_price = folium.Map(location=[52.3680, 4.9036], zoom_start=11, tiles="cartodbpositron")
map_ams_price.choropleth(
    geo_data=r'C:\neighbourhoods.geojson',
    data=df,
    columns=['neighbourhood_cleansed', 'price'],
    key_on='feature.properties.neighbourhood',
    fill_color='BuPu', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Avg',
    reset=True,
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['neighbourhood_cleansed', 'price'],
                                                      labels=True,
                                                      sticky=False),
)

map_ams_price
```

[image]

[image]

Minium Example

```py
# the price is the avg price
d = {'neighbourhood_cleansed': ['Oostelijk Havengebied - Indische Buurt', 'Centrum-Oost',
       'Centrum-West', 'Zuid', 'De Baarsjes - Oud-West', 'Bos en Lommer',
       'De Pijp - Rivierenbuurt', 'Oud-Oost', 'Noord-West', 'Westerpark',
       'Slotervaart', 'Oud-Noord', 'Watergraafsmeer',
       'IJburg - Zeeburgereiland', 'Noord-Oost', 'Buitenveldert - Zuidas',
       'Geuzenveld - Slotermeer', 'De Aker - Nieuw Sloten', 'Osdorp',
       'Bijlmer-Centrum', 'Gaasperdam - Driemond', 'Bijlmer-Oost'],
'price': [20.0,30.0,40.0,50.0,60.0,70.0,80.0,20.0,30.0,40.0,50.0,60.0,70.0,80.0,20.0,30.0,40.0,50.0,60.0,70.0,80.0,20.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

You can find the geojson here https://pastecode.io/s/a76fdvey

Comment: When using tooltips with the choropleth map, the data in the geojson file will be targeted. I was able to support tooltips for region names only by modifying it with your code. Answer is possible. In the second example of your question, the geopandas data frame contains a geometry information column and a price column, which are specified in the tooltip. See [this](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, in order to give tooltips in the choropleth map, they have to be in the geojson file, not in the dataframe value, in order to be displayed. So I used geopandas for the geojson file to be used, combined the data frames and added the price information to the geojson file. The column names in the original data frame have been modified to match the geojson file. It can also be used as a label by adding an alias name. The tooltip can be styled, so I added that as well.

```
import json
import requests
import geopandas as gpd

url = "http://data.insideairbnb.com/the-netherlands/north-holland/amsterdam/2021-09-07/visualisations/neighbourhoods.geojson"

gpd_geo = gpd.read_file(url)
gpd_geo = gpd_geo.merge(df, on='neighbourhood')
geo_json_data = gpd_geo.to_json()

import folium
from folium.plugins import FastMarkerCluster
from branca.colormap import LinearColormap
from folium.features import GeoJsonPopup, GeoJsonTooltip

map_ams_price = folium.Map(location=[52.3680, 4.9036], zoom_start=11, tiles="cartodbpositron")
choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geo_json_data,
    data=df,
    columns=['neighbourhood', 'price'],
    key_on='feature.properties.neighbourhood',
    fill_color='BuPu', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Avg',
    reset=True,
    highlight=True,
).add_to(map_ams_price)

choropleth.geojson.add_child(
    folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['neighbourhood', 'price'],
                                   aliases=['neighbourhood:', 'average_price:'],
                                   labels=True,
                                   localize=True,
                                   sticky=False,
                                   style="""
                                   background-color: #F0EFEF;
                                   border: 2px solid black;
                                   border-radius: 3px;
                                   box-shadow: 3px;
                                   """,)
)

map_ams_price
```

[image]